# What is `MNaN`?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nan

I am trying to debug some d3 code and in the console debugger I'm getting the following error returned:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,-232.4826144…".
```

However, I don't know what `MNaN` is (I'm only aware of `NaN` and *surprisingly* SO/google aren't coming up with anything particularly helpful). Also, as the error is being triggered from within d3 itself I'm not sure where/how to look to fix the issue.

Comment: Maybe the string `M` was concatenated to `NaN` before it was sent to d3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

M means [move to](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataMovetoCommands) and should be followed by pairs of numbers.

The first number in your pair is [NaN i.e. Not a Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) which is invalid, the UA's path parser will stop at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Paths in SVG look like this:

```
 <path d="M10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10"/>
```

That error is telling you that you tried to construct a path where first number was a bad value. In other words a path like:

```
 <path d="MNaN 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10"/>
```